# QGIS print layout: no options for string for path to raster image

Tags: qgis, layouts, image, string

I want to create a print layout/atlas in QGIS where an image captured by QField is displayed automatically. But now when I want to select the file path in the area Image -> Raster Image->Field Type->String, I am not shown any options -> no suitable field type found.

The atrribute fields are created as string.

Answer (score 5):

Do not select `Field type: string`, but rather `Edit` (see screenshot). There, you can define the path to your raster image(s).

*Be aware*: a string in QGIS must be enclosed in single quotes: `'`. Use forward slashes `/` or double (masked) backslashes `\\` instead of single backslashes `\` in the file path, e.g.:

`'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/image.jpg'` or `'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\image.jpg'`

[image]